# Operator overloading using Graalvm Polyglot with Scala and Python

Tags: python, scala, graalvm

I'm playing around with Graalvm's very cool Polyglot feature so I can evaluate Python from a Scala application.

The test REPL code is below. If I run it, and enter the following code I can evaluate `v.__add__(1)` fine. I get this:

```
>>> v
evaluating v
evaluated got Value(7)
>>> v.__add__(1)
evaluating v.__add__(1)
evaluated got Value(8)
>>>
```

Is there any way to evaluate `v + 1`?
I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'foreign' and 'int'` when I try.

Here's the test REPL code:

```
import org.graalvm.polyglot.{Context, Source}

import scala.annotation.targetName
import scala.util.control.NonFatal

case class Value(v: Int) {
  @targetName("__add__")
  def +(i: Int): Value = Value(v + i)
}

class Python(context: Context, v: Value) {
  private val language = "python"

  context.getBindings(language).putMember("v", v)

  def eval(code: String): AnyRef = {
    try {
      val source = Source
        .newBuilder(language, code, "<shell>")
        .interactive(false)
        .buildLiteral()

      println(s"evaluating $code")
      val res = context.eval(source)
      println(s"evaluated got $res")
      res
    } catch {
      case NonFatal(e) =>
        println(s"error evaluating $code")
        e.printStackTrace()
        null
    }
  }
}

object Python {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val context = Context
      .newBuilder("python")
      .allowAllAccess(true)
      .build()

    val python = new Python(context, Value(7))

    while (true) {
      val line = scala.io.StdIn.readLine(">>> ")
      python.eval(line)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point GraalPy does not allow to override the Python "magic" methods like this. "Foreign" objects get class "foreign", which [defines](https://github.com/oracle/graalpython/blob/master/graalpython/com.oracle.graal.python/src/com/oracle/graal/python/builtins/objects/foreign/ForeignObjectBuiltins.java) some of those "magic" methods in a way that they call appropriate lower level [Truffle interop messages](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/graalvm-as-a-platform/language-implementation-framework/InteropMigration/). You can see them like this:

```
>>> dir(type(x))
['__add__', '__and__', '__bases__', '__bool__', '__call__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__divmod__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__floordiv__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__index__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__instancecheck__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__next__', '__or__', '__radd__', '__rand__', '__rdivmod__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rmul__', '__ror__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__rxor__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__truediv__', '__truffle_richcompare__', '__xor__']
```

The issue is that the Python type of your object is not the Java/Scala class, but "foreign". The methods and fields you define are Python attributes belonging to the object instance, but "magic" methods for operations like `+` are looked up on the type => the "foreign" type. See also https://github.com/oracle/graalpython/issues/249.

For the time being, while you could implement the lower level Truffle interop messages on Scalar/Java side, I would actually suggest trying doing it from the "other" side. You can define Python classes that wrap the Scala/Java object and implement the "magic" methods appropriately:

```
class ScalaWrapper:
    def __init__(self): self.delaget = delegate
    def __add__(self, other): delegate.__add__(other)
```

you can instantiate this from Scala/Java along those lines:

```
Value wrapperInstance = context.getBindings("python").getMember("ScalaWrapper").newInstance(myScalaObjToBeWrapped);
```

or you can instantiate it also in Python.

Comment: The wrapper idea is nice and works really well. Thanks.

Comment: Btw. I think that this project took similar approach to bridge Ruby and R on GraalVM: https://github.com/rbotafogo/galaaz